# Animation slide down from top

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

How would you do an animation like this.
The new element should slide with its full height from the invisible area to the visible area.
[image: Slide down]

Comment: i have no code. there are plenty methods with jquery build in like append().slideDown(). But it is all different, since the new element starts with height 0.

Comment: Hello Derek. Anything?

Comment: @A.K No, he was just fascinated by similar names...

Comment: instead of chatting here you could post some ideas :)

Comment: @bergman: How we can without your efforts?

Comment: You dont need to write any code i could implement easily, since i didnt do this either. Just thoughts and ideas would be nice to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am aware that this was asked for jQuery but if you are not aware that this can be done with CSS as well, so I considered posting a CSS answer, if you don't want a CSS solution, you can simply ignore this post.

I've made this from scratch, am using CSS3 `@keyframes` animation, and am using `animation-delay` to control the fall of each element, rest is self explanatory..

Yea, am also using `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` so that you `div` positions don't reset.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s937y/) *(Please use Firefox to check the demo, if you want to support Chrome and other browsers, you can simply add proprietary properties to support them)*

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block_1">Hello</div>
    <div class="block_2">Hello</div>
    <div class="block_3">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap > div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 280px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}

.wrap > div.block_1 {
    animation-name: block1;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.wrap > div.block_2 {
    animation-name: block2;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.wrap > div.block_3 {
    animation-name: block3;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes block1 {
    0% {
        top: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes block2 {
    0% {
        top: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 40px;
    }
}

@keyframes block3 {
    0% {
        top: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 80px;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow o_o. what a nice idea! Yes i prefer jquery, but i give it a try!

Comment: @bergman jQuery is no different, use `transition` property in CSS and than tweak the `top` using `.css()`

Comment: i tried it again. The new element should supress the other elements with also sliding down. So the new element should stay on top.

Comment: @bergman swap the `top` values or use multiple animations so that when the second one slides, the first one moves down as well..