# display LI item one By one in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul>
    <li>AS-1</li>
    <li>QW-2</li>
    <li>PQ-3</li>
</ul>

li{
  display: inline-block;
}


$('li').hide().each(function( i ) {  
  $(this).delay( i * 400 ).fadeIn().siblings().next('li:first');  
});
```

Comment: I don't see any qusetion here, also, nothing much is shared here, we can't really answer your question, but if you are interested in CSS solution than you can go for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243282/animation-slide-down-from-top/22243384#22243384

Comment: Working fine!!http://jsfiddle.net/M6sd2/

Comment: this programe run properly but i want that show in this way, first it shows AS-1 then AS-1 hide and then QW-2 will show again Qw-2 hide and PQ-3 show and in same way PQ-3 hide and AS-1 show.

Comment: Mr.Alien actually what i am trying to get i will explain please read the problem and give the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
function fadeLi(elem) {
    elem.delay().fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut(500, function () {
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            fadeLi(elem.next());
        } else {
            fadeLi(elem.siblings(':first'));
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('ul li').hide();
    fadeLi($('ul li:first'));
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LyzTF/2/)**

Comment: hi,Felix i have accept your answer now can u plz go through my next quey which still not resolved here is the link;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583874/onresize-the-page-fadein-fade-out-not-working
please give me your feedback on them